# Using Responsive Web Design...divs not moving under each other...pushing to the side

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm using responsive design for a website and I'm having trouble with the elements moving into the right place. For @media screen and (max-width: 790px) I've set two of the blocks to move one under the other but then the block under them is pushed to the side rather than under. Please see the site here and adjust the browser window to get a better idea of the issue http://www.concept82.com/rd/grrrr.html.

Here is my code:

```
<style>
body {
margin: 0px;
font-size: 100%;
}
img {
max-width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1500px;
}
#tncontainer{
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
background-color: #B30000;
}
#topnav {
width: 96%;
height: 35px;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 960px;
}
#mncontainer {
width: 100%;
background-color: #FFF;
height: 150px;
}
#mainnav {
width: 96%; /*960*/
height: 150px;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 960px;
background-color: #CFF;
}
#logo {
width: 20%; /*200*/
height: 150px;
float: left;
background-color: #CCC;
}
#nav {
width: 79%; /*760*/
float: right;
height: 150px;
background-color: #666;
z-index: 1;
}
#cicontainer {
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 450px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1500px;
}
#coverimagecenter {
background: url(http://www.concept82.com/rd/images/coverimage2.jpg) no-repeat center;
height: 450px;
background-size: cover;
overflow: hidden;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 790px) {
#logo, #nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: clear;
}
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="tncontainer">
    <div id="topnav">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mncontainer">
    <div id="mainnav">
    <div id="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cicontainer">
    <div id="coverimagecenter">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `float: clear;`  What you want is `float: none;`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 790px) {
#logo, #nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;  /*fixed this to say none instead of clear */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Still didn't solve my problem. Now the lower element disappears (goes behind image?). The image will not move down the page as the window is scaled down.

Comment: @KristinShoffnerTanner  That's because your #mainnav ID, has a height of 150px.  Doubling that to 300px will fix it.  The nav is not behind the image, rather it is hidden by that 150px height.  Extending the height will push the image div down and expose the nav thats "hidden".

This is a classic example of avoiding absolute heights unless you have a very specific and valid reason to set a height.

Comment: @KristinShoffnerTanner  I highly recommend you learn how to utilize some form of web developer tools, such as Firebug (for firefox) or Chrome Dev Tools.  If you are using Chrome, just hit F12, this will allow you to highlight elements.  Took me 10 seconds to identify your problem through these tools.  They are essential for debugging layouts like this, and will help you immensely.

Comment: Thank you! I had actually tried that but I forgot to set both the #mainnav and #mccontainer to height: 300px so it was not working. Sorry for silly question! I've been starring at a computer too long today/I'm still learning.